# gnome keyring password after changing distribution from fedora to debian

Tags: debian, fedora, password-management, gnome-keyring

I changed one system from `Fedora 14` to `Debian stable`. Our user homes are on a NFS share. So they have been exactly remounted into the new system. It seems all is running fine, but when using passwords on the desktop (handled by `gnome-keyring`), the password is asked (which before equals the login pw). Entering this password will **not** open the keyring.
I think it may have something in common by the way, the password get stored: The hashes in /etc/shadow differ, as `Debian stable` uses `SHA-512` (`$6...`) hashwords, while those from `Fedora` are `Blowfish` (`$2...`)... But this is only an idea.
I'm searching for a solution to reuse those keyrings... Entering (**valid**) passwords will not open them... (This it not a hacking question!)
Do I have to reset all keyrings - or is there a way to get them back alive?

Comment: First, no, the hashes stored in /etc/shadow are used only by pam_unix and only for authenticating the user during logins. The hashes are salted (identical passwords can result in different hashes), can be made using different algorithms (even for two users in the same system), are unreadable by mere mortals (only by root), and are not necessarily stored locally (for example, authentication using Kerberos or LDAP); because of these reasons, they would be completely useless as encryption keys, and are not used as such. The passwords used by Keyring are separate and aren't stored at all.

Comment: Thanks @grawity - it know you details - but that was the only idea, I had... Are there any further solutions for my problem? In other words: `Why can't gnome-keyring data (from fedora) be read/opened by debian with the valid passwords?`